# setting the scale of matlab figure

Tags: matlab

[image]

In the above image, I'd like to change 10^1 to a more beautiful way, like 10_superscript(1).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, having Latex style formatting is not supported for the tick labels. However there is a method described here http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/09/24/tex-interpreter-in-x-tick-and-y-tick-labels/ which might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Matlab are you using? In 2012b it is already in latex style.

Comment: @FihopZz you are welcome. If it was helpful to you, you can up vote the answer or even accept it :-)